# print total salary of all employees against each employee data

Tags: datastage

the input I have is

```
empid salary
10   1000
20   2000
30   3000
40   5000
```

the desired output in datastage 9.1 is

```
empid   salary   totalsal
10      1000     11000
20      2000     11000
30      3000     11000
40      5000     11000
```

the solution I found is shown in the image below. My question is is there any easy method to achieve this desired result as I couldnt think of any.
Thank you for taking time to read this

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical fork join example. You fork the data to get the aggregation and join it back to the original data. This is also the ways doing it in SQL (with a subselect).
An alternative would be a transformer with a loop.
You are asking of an easy method - so what is "easy"? 
A transformer would only be a single stage while you need more but on the other hand this is maybe clearer and therefore easier.

A short explanation how this could be done with a loop in a transformer stage.

1. Use SaveInputRecord() to store the data of a group
2. Aggregate the salary (for the group)
3. Retrieve the stored rows with GetSavedInputRecord() when LastRowInGroup() is true

Doing it over the whole data would even be possible without the grouping stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use a transformer(note that you are enabling sequential access in transformer. Else partitions will calculate wrong value).
 So now keep a stage variable (lets say svarTotSal)that will add up the salary for each record. Then simply delcare a field with TOTAL_SALARY in transformer output and in derivation give svarTotSal. 
That will do.

Thanks
Sourabh